# Criar script onde se uma coluna não estiver vazia escreva " mensagem " em outro coluna

Tags: google-sheets

Se a coluna Nº 6 não for Vazia, o script carimba "realizar empréstimos" na coluna Nº 13.
Tentei realizar algo como o **script abaixo**, pois poderia realizar por uma fórmula,mas não pode ter fórmulas nesta coluna Nº 13.

Como eu poderia ajustar um script para esse evento ?

```
function onEdit() {
   var ActiveSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var capture = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
   if(capture.getColumn() == 6  && ActiveSheet.getName() == 'PLANILHA DE ATIVIDADES')  {
     var add = capture.offset(0, +13);
     var write = "realizar empréstimos;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificando a função onEdit implementei um script do Google Apps Script que funcionou bem para a solução que eu estava tentando realizar. Segue modelo do script abaixo.
A explicação do código é:  Se célula da coluna 9 for diferente de vazio, então irá adicionar a 4 colunas a frente da coluna 9,o texto "realizar empréstimos"

function onEdit() {
 var ActiveSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var capture = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
if(capture.getColumn() == 9  && ActiveSheet.getName() == 'PLANILHA DE ATIVIDADES')  {
     var add = capture.offset(0, 4);
     var write = "realizar empréstimos .";
     add.setValue(write);
   };
}